# Cannot create sqlite database in Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to create a sqlite database in Java, I have been given the following code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Database 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Connection dbConnection = null;

        try
        {
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.sqlite:test.db");
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println( ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage() );

        } //End try catch block

    } //End main method

} //End Database class
```

However, when I run the program it gives me the error "java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address: jdbc.sqlite:test.db"

I am using a MAC and have read/write permissions for the system. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: I think you need to provide a database URL there...?

Comment: worth remembering, that calling `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");` might be necessary in order to make it work. Of course answer provided below points out the main reason your code fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url should start with jdbc:sqlite (: instead of .). See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_JDBC_using_SQLite/Connecting

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was something so tiny!! Must have missed it each time I was comparing! Thanks a lot